# Would like tips and advice on updating website URL and Server Path in EE1 to a subdomain

Tags: ee1, migration, path

I'm doing a major re-desing of an old EE1 site and would like to stick a copy of the old site on the subdomain archives.mystie.com for future access.  With EE2 there are wonderful addons like REElocate to make this process easier. I haven't found anything similar for EE1

I've updated my config and path fiels and I'm able to navigate the CP using the following URL structure

mysite.com/archives/systemfolder/index.php

I have a couple of questions.

### ONE

I can't seem to get it to work using the subdomain url 
archives.mysite.com/systemfolder/index.php

Not sure what could be preventing that, but if someone has some ideas I'd love to hear them.

### TWO

The paths to my file assets (images, css, js ect) are not updating. I must be missing some setting, but I just don't know what or where.

Due to limitations on newbies posting links I was not able to add the notes on what I've done so far inline.  To read what steps I've taken go to http://webbdemo.com/files/moving-ee1-site-to-subdomain.txt

NOTE: Except for one, all "links" are config settings.

Thanks for any insights or solutions!
Jules

Answer (score 2):

For your #1, can you browse static files (e.g., put a robots.txt in the root folder) at http://archives.mystie.com? Can you browse http://archives.mystie.com/robots.txt? Make sure that works, as a starting point.

From the point of view of EE, it doesn't really know that a subdomain is a subdomain--it's just a domain name / URL. So, in your config file, you should have things like this:

```
$conf['site_url'] = "http://archives.mysite.com/";
$conf['cp_url'] = "http://archives.mysite.com/systemfolder/";
```

And, for your paths, you'll want to use the full path (most likely), like:

```
$conf['system_folder'] = "/home/un/public_html/archives/systemfolder/";
```

For your #2, take a look in the control panel under: **CP Home  ›  Admin  ›  Weblog Administration  ›  File Upload Preferences**

You'll need to update your file paths for each of your file upload destinations.

(Note that if you have hard coded full URLs to http://mysite.com/... in your content entries, those won't update.)

I think, if you tweak a few things, and double-check that you have the URLs and paths right, you should be good to go.

Comment: For some reason I can't add a line break to these comments. Struggling to get my response added

Comment: RE: #1 $conf['site_url'] was not included in the config file so I added it.

Comment: After a small tweak to my htaccess file I was able to get to http://archives.mystite.com/robots.txt

Comment: I'm really close to getting the site to work on the new subdomain. 
The main issue that I can see right now is that the templates are not updating, even after I clear all the caches.
I've updated my basepath to the template file directory to /home/username/public_html/arhives/memanager/templates.
Is there some other setting location that needs to be updated?

Comment: NOTE: Just to be clear --- I'm updating the files locally and uploading them to to the server.

Comment: @JulesWebb Double-check in Templates / Global Template Preferences in the control panel that "Basepath to Template File Directory" has the correct path--it should have a / at the end. Then, edit and save a template via the control panel, and then download and open that file locally--you should see your change. It that's all good, your template path is correct. If not, something is up with your path and/or template folder permissions.

Comment: RE: Double-check in Templates / Global Template Preferences --
Good call -- I had mispelled "archives" in the path

Comment: I'm having two more issues. The first isn't causing any problems, it's just a mystery to me. The other is preventing the images from showing up.

Comment: 1) I'm getting a "?" in the url's that are using the template code {title_permalink="template-name"}

Example: http://archives.mysite.com/?/mytemplate/category/category-name/

Comment: 2) The images are not presenting and I'm getting a "Forbidden" error message "You don't have permission to access /memanager/templates/images/subpgs/img.jpg on this server."
NOTE: if I copy and past the image link in a new browser tab the image presents. So the mapping is correct.  I checked the htaccess file and the only thing left there is the "include method" to remove index.php from the URL's

Comment: @JulesWebb, sounds generally like there's still something wrong with the folder paths and/or permissions. It definitely sounds subtle or tricky, which makes it hard to know what to suggest you do next. I'd suggest trying to get everything working with no htaccess--looking at pages with index.php in the URL. Also, you're using {title_permalink="template-group/template-name"}, right?

Comment: I did as you suggested and it doesn't seem to be the htaccess file.

Comment: I found an error in my config.php I had a typo in my $conf['system_folder'] = "/systemfolder"; Once fixed all the background images showed up, but the inline images still act like the mapping is wrong. If I copy and paste the image url in a new browser tab the image does show up.

Comment: I found another issue, which is hopefully a clue as to what is going on. when I go the the modules page in the CP the page is totally blank. I'm hoping you can give me a lead on this one because I don't know where to start troubleshooting that.

Comment: The images aren't loading due to a permissions issue "You don't have permission to access ....jpg on this server." But I just spent an hour on the phone with hosting support and they confirmed that there is nothing in my htaccess file that's preventing the images from loading and they checked the permissions on my folders and files. As far as they can tell I'm good. So that points to some setting in EE, but I'm clueless as to what that might be. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @JulesWebb it sounds like EE is pointing to the wrong folder--maybe one that doesn't exist, or otherwise one that doesn't have the right permissions. Also, do you really have your images under your templates folder? If so, did that work for you in the past?

Comment: RE: pointing to the wrong folder  ---- I know, but if the rest of the CP is showing and functioning correctly I must have the correct path. And I double checked the "modules" folder is present and accounted for. RE:Permissions - could be, but where do I look?

Comment: RE: images in templates folder  --- Yeah, I know... This was the first EE site I built and I was learning as I went. At the time there weren't a lot of educational EE resources out there. My brother was the guinea pig in this instance! LOL. Anyways, it did function just fine.

Comment: @JulesWebb maybe you should try Deeploy Helper: it shows you all of the file paths on a single page in the CP: http://www.hopstudios.com/software/deeploy_helper - make sure each path is correct, and then, via your FTP client or command line, check the folder / file permissions for each of those.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know an addon like this was available for EE1. I'll let you know how it goes. :)

Comment: I just realized that in order to take advantage of this addon I need to be able to see the modules page in my CP.   ...crap-E-ola!

Comment: Well I was able to resolve the image issue. I'm not sure how or why, but there were random .htaccess files within some of the image directories with a redirect to include "www" on the  main mysite.com url (as opposed to archives.mysite.com).

Comment: @juleswebb nice!